# Why won't the value display right after the $ sign instead of going to the next line and doing it?

Tags: html

In line 334 of this code it says "Cost Due to Ad Type" and displays a value. I just want that value to display after the money sign. but instead it breaks off to the next line. How do i prevent this?

http://jsfiddle.net/VZvDr/

```
<br>Cost due to ad type: $ <label id="derp1"></label>
```

Comment: That should be an `<output>` element, it isn't a `<label>`.

Answer (score 2):

Make label `display:inline` its probably `display:block` or if label is too general, `#derp1` should be `display:inline`

Comment: Labels are used for form inputs.  It should be pointed out that the use of a label in this context will confuse screen reader users.

Answer (score 1):

Labels are for forms, and using them in this context will confuse users that are viewing the page with a screen reader.  Use a `span` instead, which is inline by default.  The line would look like the following:

```
<br>Cost due to ad type: $<span id="derp1"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In one of your style sheets (style.css), you have the declaration `display: block;` in a rule with `label` as the selector. Removing that declaration (which causes line breaks before and after) fixes the problem at hand.

On the other hand, this is not a place for `label` at all, and the markup is invalid – the element is not a label for a labelable element. Use `span` instead. (Using `output` might seem to be more “semantic”, but it gains nothing and causes problems in browsers that do not support it, mainly old versions of IE.)